# Android: SQLite database copying an entry for dummy use

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a class a database full of objects of my `People` type. I want to implement a `Groups` feature to put certain `People` in certain `Groups`. However, when I delete a Person from a group, I just want that person to be removed from the group, not removed entirely.

So is there anyway for SQLite to give a "copy" of a `Person` to a class, like a dummy, and when you delete it, it doesn;t get deleted from the whole app, just the group?

Or should I implement this a completely different way. For example, one idea I came up with is as follows: There are ALOT of `People` which is why I used a database but there arent going to be many `Groups` so maybe I could just use an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s. Ie, there is an arraylist of `groups` and every `group` has an arraylist of `People` that belong to the group. That way, you can just delete entries from the arraylist as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is just have on table that would contain all your `People` object type. Add a column to signify which group they belong to (e.g. name the column `GroupNumber`). If you need to take them out of the group, just clear the `GroupNumber` column as needed. That way, you remove them from the Group but not from the database.

Comment: So that would mean that my `Groups` class doesn't actually contain any `People`. It just scans through the database and just displays in the listview whoever it finds with the appropriate group name?

Comment: Yes. Something like that. You can also create a `Group` Database table if you want.

Comment: Okay, thanks alot you really helped me out. I will do what you proposed in your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have another option allowing same people may belong to different groups.

SQLite has `VIEW` and `TRIGGER ... INSTEAD OF DELETE` which may be usefull in your case.

Imagine this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE People(pid, Name);
CREATE TABLE Groups(gid, Name);
CREATE TABLE PeopleGroup(gid, pid);
CREATE VIEW PeopleInGroups
    SELECT People.*, Groups.* FROM People
    JOIN PeopleGroups ON PeopleGroups.pid=People.pid
    JOIN Groups ON PeopleGroups.gid=Group.gid;
CREATE TRIGGER pigd INSTEAD OF DELETE ON PeopleInGroups BEGIN
    DELETE FROM PeopleGroup WHERE pid=OLD.pid AND gid=OLD.gid;
    END;
```

When you do

```
 SELECT * FROM PeopleInGroups;
```

you will get all people with groups assigned.

Then you can also

```
DELETE FROM PeopleInGroups WHERE pid=123;
```

which will execute trigger and simply remove this person from all groups.